# how to ignore part of URL in Yii

Tags: php, url-rewriting, yii

In my project all js and css url is look like 
http://my.domain.com/XXX/js/script.js
were XXX - is a version of release wich is incrementing with each commit to master. 
But actually all scripts are located in http://my.domain.com/js/script.js without XXX
so i need to ignore this XXX. 
How i can do it. Trying to do it with url manager, but without result.
It was done, because of CDN is ignoring ?V=XXX at the end of links and returns all cached results

Answer (score 0):

You could use a .htaccess file in your application root that contains this

```
#Forward all non-existent files/directories to Yii
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) XXX/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

## edit:

after understanding the question, i think you should have a post-commit hook on your versioning system that changes the XXX in your .htaccess file

Comment: XXX is changing automatically

Comment: it is possible, but i want to realize it via Yii